Mercator CRS that covers the extent -90,-180 to 90,180
Is there a EPSG CRS for Mercator that isn't deprecated and covers -90.0,-180.0 to 90.0,180.0?

https://epsg.org/crs_6893/WGS-84-World-Mercator-EGM2008-height.html

I'm not sure how this would be useful because of the distortion at the poles. For epsg:6893 from equator to 89N is 30 million units (metres), from equator to 90N, one more degree north, is 242 million metres.

@Spacedman, I read the background map from a WMS (mercator) and overlays it with flight information from Jeppesen (Boing). The flight data is different types of polygons all over the globe from -90 to 90 and 180 to -180.

Yeah, its probably okay until you try and plot it in that projection.

By definition, the poles are infinitely far from the Equator, so no, you can't define a global Mercator that includes the poles.
